# How do I print two variable at the same time using variable argument? Is there a better method to do this?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I was learning and practising c-programming and I got an idea to print a player in a battle field made using 'x' and '0' the '0' is the place where the player 'x' can be placed and I want to be able to place multiple 'x' player in one battle field using variable argument in c. I thought to create this to exercise how I could simplify my code if I needed too. When I insert only one 'x' its fine but when I insert multiple 'x' this code doesn't work.(I mean I can create structure and pass it and put as many 'x' as I want to but this way is the lengthy way) So I used variable argument. Any idea on how I could modify this code to put two or more 'x' in same battle field in the easiest way possible. I was also thinking of using file handling, putting the positionx and positiony values in txt file and using it.

Can this work using variable argument? If yes how? If no then how should I do it in very effective and fast way?
My code is (my code looks like it is working but the position of 'man2' is not right :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

struct player{     
    int positionx;
    int positiony;
};

void placePlayer(int num,...);

int main(){
    printf("Battle Feild : \n");

    struct player man1;
    man1.positionx=1;
    man1.positiony=5;

    struct player man2;
    man2.positionx=4;
    man2.positiony=3;

    /* struct player man3;
    man3.positionx=2;//I want to insert as many x as I want
    man3.positiony=1; */
    placePlayer(2,man1,man2);

}

void placePlayer(int num,...){
    va_list valist;
    va_start(valist,num);
        struct player posi=va_arg(valist,struct player);
        printf("-----------\n");
    for(int j=0; j<=6; j++){
        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
            if( (i==posi.positionx && j==posi.positiony) ||
                (i==posi.positionx && j==posi.positiony) || 
                (i==va_arg(valist,struct player).positionx 
                && j==va_arg(valist,struct player).positiony) || 
                (i==va_arg(valist,struct player).positionx &&
                 j==va_arg(valist,struct player).positiony)){
                printf("X");
            }
            else{
                printf("0");
            }
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    printf("-----------\n");
    va_end(valist);
}
```

output:

```
Battle Feild : 
-----------
0000X000000
00000000000
00000000000
00000000000
00000000000
0X000000000
00000000000
-----------
```

Comment: If you want to have an arbitrary number of something, use an array, not separate variables.

Comment: yeah but this would get tougher using array.

Comment: You're not processing all the arguments, just the first one.

Comment: Arrays make it easier, not harder. You can't access variables dynamically, you can't loop over them. You can only have as many players as you've declared `manX` variables.

Comment: i know but how do i process that is the problem i couldn't solve

Comment: For each position in the grid, you have to loop over all the arguments, searching for a player with that X/Y position. If you find it, you print X. If you get to the end of the loop without finding it, you print 0

Comment: yeah may be multidimensional array is the way to go in this program right?

Comment: Yes. The grid should be a 2-D array. Initialize it to all `0`. Then you can loop over the players, and for each of them assign `X` to `grid[player.positionx][player.positiony]`. Finally you just print the grid.

Comment: But you should also have the players in an array, not separate variables, so you can have as many players as you want.

Comment: i tried some ways but i couldn't figure it out answer it in answer section by modifying my code.

Comment: i mean i couldn't figure to make this program work using variable argument

Comment: i think using variable argument in this program is not workable. It can't be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array for the players, not multiple variables and variable argument list.

In `placeplayer()`, use a 2-dimensional array to hold the grid, and fill it in from the player positions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PLAYER_COUNT 2
#define GRID_WIDTH 10
#define GRID_HEIGHT 7

typedef struct player{
    int positionx;
    int positiony;
} player;

void placePlayer(int num, player players[]);

int main(){
    printf("Battle Feild : \n");

    player man[PLAYER_COUNT] = {{1, 5}, {4, 3}};
    placePlayer(PLAYER_COUNT, man);

}

void placePlayer(int num, player players[]){
    char grid[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH];
    // Initialize array to all 0
    for(int j=0; j < GRID_HEIGHT; j++){
        for(int i=0; i < GRID_WIDTH; i++){
            grid[j][i] = '0';
        }
    }
    // Place X for the players
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        grid[players[i].positionx][players[i].positiony] = 'X';
    }
    printf("-----------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_HEIGHT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < GRID_WIDTH; j++) {
            putchar(grid[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    printf("-----------\n");
}
```

Comment: why did you did +1 why is null terminator necessary?

Comment: So we can print the row as a string, rather than looping over each character in the row.

Comment: i understood all that and i tried this program too after removing +1 the code prints many 0s i dont understand why it is doing that what is really going on

Comment: ok but we could have printed it like a character too right?

Comment: Yes, we could have. I just chose to simplify it like this.

Comment: If you remove `+1` then you aren't leaving room for the null terminator, and you can't treat the row as a string.

Comment: I've rewritten it without that.

Comment: people like you are so much encouragement to keep coding thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67223211/expression-tree-operations-with-characters/67231181#67231181   please could you look at this code where i tried to make a calculator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231517/discussion-between-coder-manish-and-barmar).